# Can't set secrets as env vars Actions Workflow

Tags: github-actions

For this github actions workflow:

```
name: Manual_Run

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'Environment'
        default: 'Stage'
        required: true
        type: string
      

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      SERVICE_NAME: Deployment test suite execution
      INPUT_ENV: ${{ github.event.inputs.env }}

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Setup python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'
        cache: 'pip'

    - name: Cache dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-

    - name: Import Secrets
      uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v2
      with:
        /.../
        secrets: |
          secret/path/to/dir name | NAME;
          

    - name: Install python requirements
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run Pytest
      env:
        NAME: ${{ steps.secrets.outputs.NAME }}
        
      run: python py_script.py
```

I am trying to set secrets as variables, then use those variables to create env vars that I can access via python script using os.environ.get

Problem is in my py_script.py I m trying to access name env var, but it is always empty string:

```
print("len of name env var", len(os.environ.get('NAME', '')))
```

Trying this path to access secrets still aint working

```
          NAME: ${{ secrets.NAME}}
```

SO I assume somewhere something isn't clicking
One thing I know for certain the secret path is ok and has value, the rest I am unsure

Comment: You have no `id` set on the secrets step, so you can't reference it with `steps.secrets`.

Comment: Yup that's it, thank you, could u add this as answer

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the [`steps` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context):

> The steps context contains information about the steps in the current job that have an [`id`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsid) specified and have already run.

That `id` is missing in your secrets step: you need

```yaml
    - name: Import Secrets
      id: secrets
      uses: hashicorp/vault-action@v2
      with:
        /.../
        secrets: |
          secret/path/to/dir name | NAME;
```